# React hook form dynamic fields validations

Tags: yup, react-hook-form

My task is to implant a functionality that includes dynamically creation of fields and apply validation on those dynamically created fields.

I have found a prefect example that fits my use case which is here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-form-dynamic-form-example) but the issue that I am facing is every time I try to download the example from stackblitz and run locally  I get error below error:

```
{"tickets":{"message":"tickets must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `{\n \"0name\": \"\\\"\\\"\",\n \"0email\": \"\\\"\\\"\",\n \"1name\": \"\\\"\\\"\",\n \"1email\": \"\\\"\\\"\"\n}`).\n If \"null\" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`","type":"typeError"}}
```

I am wondering if someone could help me run this example locally, rest I can work out.

Many thanks :)

Comment: I just tried and it works for me locally. What version of nodejs do you have ? And what commands do you use to run it locally ?

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for replying the application is starting up but when I select the ticket prices drop down and select the number from the drop down it generates the fields with no issue the problem comes up when you press submit and it does not validate the from.

And if you log the errors it shows the error I specify in the question.

I have tried on node 12 and 14 its the same issue that comes up. I can try on version 16 as well but I doubt that's  going to help much.

To run the project I am using combination of below commands

yarn install
yarn start